# Python unittest mocking not working as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing, python-unittest

I got this project structure:

```
my_project 
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── helpers
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── integration
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_app.py
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_helpers.py
```

So far, unit testing for `helpers` hasn't been complicated, i'd patch 3rd parties and some functions within helpers.

The integration testing in `tests/integration/test_app.py` is being a bit of a blocking point because the patching isn't doing what i need it do to.
For example, I got a method like this:

helpers/**init**.py:

```py
def compute_completeness_metric(
        vendor,
        product,
        fields,
        endpoint):
    body = {"vendor": vendor, "product": product, "fields": fields}
    response_json = requests.post(
        "http://example.com", json=body)
    if response_json.status_code != 200:
        response_json = "Can't compute"
    else:
        response_json = response_json.json()
    return response_json
```

Now, in app.py, I call it the following way:

```py
from helpers import compute_completeness_metric
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    final_results = {}
    final_results = compute_completeness_metric(vendor, product, fields, endpoint)
...
```

And when testing, I try to patch it the following way:

```py
    @patch('data_quality.helpers.compute_completeness_metric')
    def test_app(self, mock_compute_completeness_metric):
      mock_compute_completeness_metric.return_value = "blablabla"
```

But the mocked methods do not return what they're supposed to return, instead execute themselves as if they weren't mocked.

Am I missing something? Should I be mocking the methods within `get_rule_data_models()` ?

TIA!

Comment: Please read [mre]. Can you recreate the problem with a simpler folder structure? With simpler business logic? Can you clearly and simply show an expected and actual result, explicitly? We should be able to **copy and paste** code, **without changing or adding anything** to see the **exact** problem **directly**.

Comment: Sure, I'll provide new examples. Edit: done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you mock a function depends on the way it is declared or imported.

If you used

```
import helpers
...
     final_results = helpers.compute_completeness_metric(vendor, product, fields, endpoint)
```

Then mocking with `@patch('data_quality.helpers.compute_completeness_metric')` would be fine

But here you use:

```
from helpers import compute_completeness_metric
...
    final_results = compute_completeness_metric(vendor, product, fields, endpoint)
```

That means that in app.py you no longer use the symbol from the `helpers` module but a local symbol that points to where `helpers.compute_completeness_metric` pointed at import time. That means that you have to patch the symbol in the `app` module:

```
@patch('data_quality.app.compute_completeness_metric')
def test_app(self, mock_compute_completeness_metric):
  mock_compute_completeness_metric.return_value = "blablabla"
```

Comment: So the context of the patching doesn't depend on the method's module, but rather it's location?

Comment: The mock module cannot replace the code of a method. It just have a name point to a different code. That means that you have to declare the name that you are using.